# Where to save words file for Hangman game on android?

Tags: java, android, string, text, android-resources

I'm trying to make a simple Hangman game for android (without using any libraries like libGdx) and first problem I encountered was this. I don't know where should I put all the words that I made for my game. Should I make it a simple txt file or XML resource file? Should I put that file into new directory or into values directory?
I'll need to read that data file and put all words to String array. File will not be modified during game.
Any advice would be very welcome.

Comment: Why not a sqlite database?

Comment: You can keep your dictionary with a .txt file in assets folder and read it to a string array. But if your dictionary has millions of word, you must use a sqlite db.

Comment: I didn't know about sqlite and haven't even used any database before but I might try. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be best to make use of android's built in sqlite database. If you would use a text file you would have to parse all of the data into an array then pull out a random record to use for your game. If you use a database you are able to pull a random record from the database with a single query. Sqlite would make more efficient use of your resources.